# Android: How to ZoomOut a single page in ViewPager if user zoomed it in?

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager

I'm using WebView in ViewPager to display images from internet. WebView is used because of it's built in zoom controls. I want to enable my users to zoom images in pager, but when they swipe to the next image, to restore original zoom on previous image.
I tried few things, from which only one gives me the funcionality I desire, but it is not a good enough solution, because there is a blinking when swipeing through pages.

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(
            ) {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            currImg = arg0;
            //System.out.println("On page selected");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //System.out.println("On page scrolled");

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arg0 == 2) {
                //mPager.getAdapter().
                mPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                System.out.println("Notifying Data Set Changed " + mPager.getCurrentItem());
            }

        }
    });
```

In ViewPager adapter I have overrided getItemPosition so it would return POSITON_NONE.
This is not a good solution because pages are refreshed on every swipe and there is no smooth transition between pages. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has shown to be a best way to revert the page to initial zoom state:

```
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            System.out.println("onPageSelected -> arg0 = " + arg0);

            if (currPage != arg0) {
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                currPage = arg0;
            }
        }
    });
```

Than, in your adapter class you override getItemPosition method like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    if (((ExtendedWebView) object).getScale() != webScale) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
    return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
}
```

Comment: what is webScale and what is the initial value of currPage.

Comment: Oh, sorry I haven't written it. It's the initial scale of a WebView.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just revert the page to the initial zoom state?

Comment: That is what I've been trying to do. But there is a problem because i can't access the child view of ViewPager when swipe is detected. I'm new to Android, so maybe there is something that I have overlooked. On page listener is set up in onCreate method, and webViews are set up in instantiateItem method.

Answer (score 0):

Well the blinking you see is cause is loading again the data and generating the view, saw for you maybe is just a little blink but if you but more thing in it or you add some downloading or streaming for each view, that blink will become in a white page loading.
What you can do is on the [page changed listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) you should add code to set the current zoom level on the last webview.

Example:

```
lastPos = pos - 1;
((WebView) mPager.getChildAt(lastPos)).getSettings().setDefaultZoom(zoomLevel);
```

**NOTE:** This is just an EXAMPLE, maybe you have to change something depending on your configuration before this can work with your code.

this example assumes that the WebView is the only child of each page from the viewpager, if you have more or if the WebView is inside a relative or linear layout, then you will have to add the code to retrieve the WebView and the apply the change on the zoom.

**UPDATE:**

If you want the image to take all the screen inside the webview, you can do this.
in this case "web" is my object of type "WebView". Good luck.

```
web.loadData("<html><head></head><body><img src='" + url //IMAGE URL
+ "' style='width:100%;height:98%;max-width:100%;max-height:98%;'></body></html>",
"text/html", "utf-8"); //THIS WILL FIT THE IMAGE TO TAKE ALL THE SCREEN
```

Comment: I managed to make this one work:
'((ExtendedWebView) mPager.getChildAt(pos)).loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, "text/html",  "UTF-8", null);'

I'm using css to make the image fit the screen (but it's not working) like this:
'String data = "<div>" +
               "<table width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\">" +
               "<tr><td style=\"vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; margin:0px\">" +
               "<img src=\""+
               url + "\"/>" + 
               "</td></tr>" +
               "</table>" +
               "</div>";'

Comment: Well seeing your code seems like you are not setting the image to take the fill width or height of the table, you are just setting the table to take the full screen, BUT you need to specify to the img tag that he also needs to take the full size of the table, and when dealing with images is better to also specify a max-width and max-height. One more thing, if you want to do it right stop using tables to arrange things, you better use css, you only need a img tag for this to work. Ex. <html><head></head><body><img src="" style=""></body></html> and that's it. Good luck

Comment: Thank you man. I will try that and post feedback after I'm done.

Comment: It's not working. I'm trying something like this:
'"<img src=\"" + url + "\" style=\"width:"+scrWidth +"px; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; margin:0px\">'

scrWidth is width of the screen in pixels.

Comment: i already made a working example and added the code to load the URL in my answer.